# Can I pick any other GPIO in my scenario?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, breadboard, ds18b20

I have a setup with a pi 3 and a breadboard. I am using a [DS18B20](http://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DS18B20-Datasheet.pdf) temperature sensor.

This is my setup (notice wrong resistor in this sketch):

[image]

As far as I can see it the sensor's second pin is the data pin.

[image]

So I am wondering could I pick any other GPIO X instead of the GPIO 4 (blue wire) in my case, e.g. GPIO 17 or GPIO 27?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DS18B20 is a (Dallas) 1-wire bus device.  You can connect multiple 1-wire devices to the same bus.  They are differentiated by their unique internal Id.

So you can connect additional devices to GPIO4.

The Pi (currently) only supports one 1-wire bus.

By default that bus is associated with GPIO4.

An entry in `/boot/config.txt` allows you to change the default GPIO.

`dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=24`

With the above example you would then need to connect your 1-wire devices to GPIO24.

Comment: Hence I would need to modify the /boot/config.txt ?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to move the bus to a different GPIO.  The change would not take effect until a reboot.